# Having trouble with a Makefile. How can I get a more verbose error?

Tags: cgo, makefile

Here is the Makefile: https://github.com/somersbmatthews/vault/blob/master/Makefile

Here is what happens when I run it:

```
somersbmatthews@pop-os:~/go/src/vault$ make static-dist dev-ui
--> Installing JavaScript assets
yarn install v1.19.1
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.75s.

> node-sass@4.14.1 install /home/somersbmatthews/go/src/vault/ui/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

node-sass build Binary found at /home/somersbmatthews/go/src/vault/ui/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node

> node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall /home/somersbmatthews/go/src/vault/ui/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at /home/somersbmatthews/go/src/vault/ui/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
node-sass@4.14.1 /home/somersbmatthews/go/src/vault/ui/node_modules/node-sass
--> Building Ember application
yarn run v1.19.1
$ ember build -prod

  INFORMATION (ember-cli-pretender)
  ember-auto-import seems to be in your package dependencies.
  As a result, you don't need pretender to be wrapped anymore.
  You can install pretender and remove ember-cli-pretender.
        
⠋ BuildingWARNING: Option "nodeWorker" is deprecated since workerpool@5.0.0. Please use "workerType" instead.
WARNING: Option "nodeWorker" is deprecated since workerpool@5.0.0. Please use "workerType" instead.
WARNING: Option "nodeWorker" is deprecated since workerpool@5.0.0. Please use "workerType" instead.
Environment: production
⠏ BuildingThe 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten
⠦ Building'@ember/string' is imported by ../../../../../../tmp/broccoli-607060b8WPADOlU6j8/cache-260-rollup/build/-private/system/normalize-model-name.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'@ember/string' is imported by ../../../../../../tmp/broccoli-607060b8WPADOlU6j8/cache-260-rollup/build/-private/adapters/build-url-mixin.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'@ember/string' is imported by ../../../../../../tmp/broccoli-607060b8WPADOlU6j8/cache-260-rollup/build/-private/system/debug/debug-adapter.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
⠏ Building[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /home/somersbmatthews/go/src/vault/ui/node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-bundle.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
Generating files needed by Storybook
Parsing /tmp/broccoli-607060b8WPADOlU6j8/out-630-broccoli_merge_trees/index.html
Generating preview-head.html
Generating files needed by Storybook
Generating .env
cleaning up...
Built project successfully. Stored in "../pkg/web_ui".
File sizes:
 - ../pkg/web_ui/assets/chunk.3.e73ac42f48b4e5ab3d48.js: 1.08 MB (316.69 KB gzipped)
 - ../pkg/web_ui/assets/node-asset-manifest.js: 1.02 KB (445 B gzipped)
 - ../pkg/web_ui/assets/vault-895816690cab246cbd3b9423defc2f53.css: 482.96 KB (56.99 KB gzipped)
 - ../pkg/web_ui/assets/vault-b8afdc29f93ad91f89268835698b0711.js: 1.2 MB (185.17 KB gzipped)
 - ../pkg/web_ui/assets/vendor-8381b7eebdb7ea85cb88b80f3029e0e8.css: 14.21 KB (3.66 KB gzipped)
 - ../pkg/web_ui/assets/vendor-ded9c2047ac30c216b8015683667178a.js: 1.82 MB (457.27 KB gzipped)
 - ../pkg/web_ui/ember-fetch/fetch-fastboot-38cfd9007f94f81f5a2bc13690efc343.js: 1020 B (562 B gzipped)
 - ../pkg/web_ui/engines-dist/kmip/assets/engine-ce86d837f49968e27331ecc744f8288d.js: 68.55 KB (9.29 KB gzipped)
 - ../pkg/web_ui/engines-dist/kmip/assets/engine-vendor-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.css: 0 B
 - ../pkg/web_ui/engines-dist/kmip/assets/engine-vendor-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.js: 0 B
 - ../pkg/web_ui/engines-dist/kmip/config/environment-0123205ae026fc9ed3e41f1d552270f8.js: 86 B (100 B gzipped)
 - ../pkg/web_ui/engines-dist/open-api-explorer/assets/engine-83cdd1e87b4c1568b63b394b62e6e0c5.js: 27.16 KB (5.14 KB gzipped)
 - ../pkg/web_ui/engines-dist/open-api-explorer/assets/engine-9dcfdf942f31c3caa1d6dfd57c3cc072.css: 3.38 KB (829 B gzipped)
 - ../pkg/web_ui/engines-dist/open-api-explorer/assets/engine-vendor-6faadde6d1de73cd00d4f818f4f60c75.css: 149.46 KB (22.77 KB gzipped)
 - ../pkg/web_ui/engines-dist/open-api-explorer/assets/engine-vendor-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.js: 0 B
 - ../pkg/web_ui/engines-dist/open-api-explorer/config/environment-6da0fcce17b2031e2559754701e92d69.js: 194 B (170 B gzipped)
 - ../pkg/web_ui/engines-dist/replication/assets/engine-52dc634acbe2629436188771450e81ba.js: 97.81 KB (15.78 KB gzipped)
 - ../pkg/web_ui/engines-dist/replication/assets/engine-vendor-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.css: 0 B
 - ../pkg/web_ui/engines-dist/replication/assets/engine-vendor-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.js: 0 B
 - ../pkg/web_ui/engines-dist/replication/config/environment-fcc3a0f22bdfd265a50708864776440a.js: 100 B (104 B gzipped)
 - ../pkg/web_ui/sw-registration-65dd6e15d4d40ce435383a9edaccfc03.js: 1.14 KB (616 B gzipped)
 - ../pkg/web_ui/sw.js: 1.26 KB (675 B gzipped)
Done in 70.33s.
--> Generating static assets
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/somersbmatthews/go/src/vault'
goimports -w $(find . -name '*.go' | grep -v pb.go | grep -v vendor)
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/somersbmatthews/go/src/vault'
==> Checking compiled UI assets...
==> Checking that build is using go version >= 1.14.7...
==> Using go version 1.15.2...
==> Removing old directory...
==> Building...
flag provided but not defined: -gcflags
Usage: gox [options] [packages]

  Gox cross-compiles Go applications in parallel.

  If no specific operating systes or architectures are specified, Gox
  will build for all pairs supported by your version of Go.

Options:

  -arch=""            Space-separated list of architectures to build for
  -build-toolchain    Build cross-compilation toolchain
  -ldflags=""         Additional '-ldflags' value to pass to go build
  -os=""              Space-separated list of operating systems to build for
  -osarch=""          Space-separated list of os/arch pairs to build for
  -output="foo"       Output path template. See below for more info
  -parallel=-1        Amount of parallelism, defaults to number of CPUs
  -verbose            Verbose mode

Output path template:

  The output path for the compiled binaries is specified with the
  "-output" flag. The value is a string that is a Go text template.
  The default value is "{{.Dir}}_{{.OS}}_{{.Arch}}". The variables and
  their values should be self-explanatory.

Platforms (OS/Arch):

  The operating systems and architectures to cross-compile for may be
  specified with the "-arch" and "-os" flags. These are space separated lists
  of valid GOOS/GOARCH values to build for, respectively. You may prefix an
  OS or Arch with "!" to negate and not build for that platform. If the list
  is made up of only negations, then the negations will come from the default
  list.

  Additionally, the "-osarch" flag may be used to specify complete os/arch
  pairs that should be built or ignored. The syntax for this is what you would
  expect: "darwin/amd64" would be a valid osarch value. Multiple can be space
  separated. An os/arch pair can begin with "!" to not build for that platform.

  The "-osarch" flag has the highest precedent when determing whether to
  build for a platform. If it is included in the "-osarch" list, it will be
  built even if the specific os and arch is negated in "-os" and "-arch",
  respectively.

make: *** [Makefile:39: dev-ui] Error 2
```

Here is the full repo: https://github.com/somersbmatthews/vault

Lines 38 and 39 in the Makefile are:

```
dev-ui: assetcheck prep
    @CGO_ENABLED=$(CGO_ENABLED) BUILD_TAGS='$(BUILD_TAGS) ui' VAULT_DEV_BUILD=1 sh -c "'$(CURDIR)/scripts/build.sh'"
```

How do I get more information on this error? "Error 2" appears twice in the code in two files as errors for a MongoDB dependency:

https://github.com/somersbmatthews/vault/blob/master/vendor/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver/auth/internal/gssapi/sspi_wrapper.h

https://github.com/somersbmatthews/vault/blob/master/vendor/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver/auth/internal/gssapi/gss_wrapper.h

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved as per https://groups.google.com/g/vault-tool/c/xyV7-FMHrEE?pli=1
use command `make bootstrap` to update gox and other go tools.

NOTE: previous versions of gox will make an empty file called bindata.go Just delete this.